# How can i send the same select values via ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

Here is the problem, i have more than 1 select in html with the same name, and the action that i do it's an update query when this select change, but the problem is when i use the other select this doesn't send the ajax request.

This select is performed with a PHP while so that's why i have more than 1 select.

**SELECT HTML:**

```
<?php
    $qu_buscarUsr = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE puesto = 2 and estado = 1 order by ap_pat, ap_mat, nombres";
    $do_qu_buscarUsr = mysql_query($qu_buscarUsr);
?>
    <select name="txtUsuario" class="form-control" id="txtUsuario" required>
        <option style="display:none;" value=""><?php echo $NombreCompleto; ?></option>
<?php
    if(mysql_num_rows($do_qu_buscarUsr) > 0){
        while($dato = mysql_fetch_array($do_qu_buscarUsr)){
?>             
            <option value="<?php echo $dato['id_user']; ?>"><?php echo $dato['nombres']." ".$dato['ap_pat']." ".$dato['ap_mat']; ?></option>
<?php 
        }
    }
?>
</select>
```

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
    $("#txtUsuario").change(function() {        
        var idGra = $("#txtIdGrado").val();
        var idGru = $("#txtIdGrupo").val();
        var idTur = $("#txtIdTurno").val();
        var idUsr = $("#txtUsuario").val();
        var dataString = 'idGrado='+idGra+'&idGrupo='+idGru+'&idTurno='+idTur+'&idUser='+idUsr;

        $("#mostrar").fadeOut();

        $.ajax({ //metodo ajax
            type: "POST", //aqui puede ser get o post
            url: "ajax/UpdtAsesor.php", //la url adonde se va a mandar la cadena a buscar
            data: dataString,
            cache: false,
            success: function(data)//funcion que se activa al recibir un dato
            {
                $("#mostrar").fadeIn();
                $("#mostrar").html(data);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

**PHP:**

```
<?php
session_start();
include("../php/php_config.php");

if(isset($_SESSION['id_user'])){
    if(isset($_POST)){
        $idGrado = $_POST['idGrado'];
        $idGrupo = $_POST['idGrupo'];
        $idTurno = $_POST['idTurno'];
        $idUser = $_POST['idUser'];
        $sql_check = "UPDATE asesores SET usuario = '".$idUser."' WHERE grado = '".$idGrado."' AND grupo = '".$idGrupo."' AND turno = '".$idTurno."' AND estado = '1'";
        $result = mysql_query($sql_check);
        if($result){
?>
            <div class="alert alert-success animated fadeInDown retraso-1 no-mgn-btm" style="text-align:center;border-radius:3px;margin:0 auto;font-weight:bold;">Se cambio de asesor para el grupo correspondiente</div>
<?php
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: You can't have multiple elements of the same name unless you want to create an array.

Comment: You also can't have multiple elements with the same `id` - which is what your question seems to be implying.

Comment: Firsr of all it's completely wrong practice to have two elements with the same id. Element ids must be unique within the one document.

Comment: Try to rename(or change id) of your own select and register event handler for both elements.

Comment: You guys are right, but the thing is that i have to set the same name for all, so... What is the way to fix that?, i've tried but i fail